# rank(A-B)=rank(A-AB)+rank(B-AB)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A, B \in M_n, A^2=A, B^2=B$

Prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A-B)=\operatorname{rank}(A-AB)+\operatorname{rank}(B-AB)$

My attempt: I use Sysvester's rank inequality

$\operatorname{rank}(A-B)=\operatorname{rank}(A-AB+AB-B)\le \operatorname{rank}(A-AB)+\operatorname{rank}(AB-B)=\operatorname{rank}(A-AB)+\operatorname{rank}(B-AB)$

But I don't know how to prove $\operatorname{rank}(A-B)\ge\operatorname{rank}(A-AB)+\operatorname{rank}(B-AB)$

Comment: using the info that $A^2 = A,B^2 = B$ we can say $\text {rank}(A-AB) + \text {rank}(B-AB) = \text {rank}(A(A-B)) + \text {rank}((B-A)B)$

Comment: thank you :D, just solved it by Frobenius